# Thread Synchronization not getting expected output

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

i am not getting any output but i am expecting output as *THREAD1 THREAD2* below is the code..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void* fun(void *arg)
{
   char *msg;
   msg = (char*)arg;
   cout<<msg<<endl;
}

int main()
{

   pthread_t t1,t2;

   t1 = pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD1");
   t2 = pthread_create(&t2,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD2");

   pthread_join(t1,NULL);
   pthread_join(t2,NULL);
  // sleep (2);
   return 0;
}
```

I changed above code to

```
   pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD1");
   pthread_create(&t2,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD2");
```

Now i am getting *THREAD2 THREAD1* but i need *THREAD1 THREAD2*

Now i changed my code to >

```
pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD1");
pthread_join(t1,NULL);    

pthread_create(&t2,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD2");
pthread_join(t2,NULL);
```

Now my result is Proper as *THREAD1 THREAD2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t1 = pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fun,(void*)"THREAD1");
```

That's not good. `pthread_create` returns an integer return code, not a `pthread_t`. You're overwriting the `t1` and `t2` with stuff that shouldn't be there, and the subsequent `pthread_join` calls are likely to crash or produce otherwise non-predictable results.

```
int rc1 = pthread_create(...);
if (rc1 != 0) { 
  // handle error
}
```

Also `fun` needs to return *something* the way you've defined it. Or change its return type to void.

Comment: i have corrected it but now i am getting THREAD2 and then THREAD1 ...why so?

Comment: Those threads run independently. You can't guess the order. You'll need some form of synchronization if you want one to run before the other (or join with thread one before creating thread two).

Comment: yes before creating thread2 if i am using thread_join its giving me proper result...but in previous case what techniqe i can use?

Comment: You need to write some code so that the function that thread 2 runs waits for something that thread 1's function does. Look into semaphores or condition variables.

Comment: And pthread_join is only for function main just it will wait (calling thread is main ) so here in main unless and until thread 1 and 2 has not finish it will wait right(execution of main will not be finished)?

Comment: You means to say some kind of MUTEX so that thread 2 will wait and be synchronized with thread 1?

Comment: Yes, `pthread_join` makes the calling thread block until the other thread is finished. Mutex only doesn't seem like the right approach if you want ordering. I mean what I wrote: condition variables or semaphores.